# Should you include patch files in your project and source control?

Tags: configuration

- If yes, then what if you have different patches for different environments?

  - Would you then put a transform(for publishing) on the Patch.config file?

(same question - put transforms on ConnectionStrings.config and include that in source/publish too?)

Comment: `ConnectionStrings.config` should _NEVER_ be in source control.

Comment: Hi @RichardSeal - interesting, I hadn't come across that view so strongly before. If you could flesh that out into an answer as to why, and suggested approach, I think that'd be really beneficial!

Comment: For an answer on the Connection Strings, you should open a new question, as it would not directly relate to your main question. As per SSE guidelines, each post should only deal with a single question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they should be.

Depending on your build/deployment setup you may find that replacement variables enable you to have fewer patches and to differentiate between environments. Alternatively you can have patches for each environment and remove when packaging up artifacts before deployment.

The same would hold true for configuration transforms. The build server pulls the latest changes from source control at which point configuration transforms can be processed.

As may be pointed out by many in the community, storing any file which contains paths to databases, passwords, and anything sensitive should not be in the file committed to source control. This is where variable replacements come in handy.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for this. Would it also be fair to say that you should **not** have **any** of the base/vanilla `.config` files in source? (`.config` files you get from the base install via SIM for example)

Comment: In most cases, any file that is included with a vanilla Sitecore installation should not be tracked by source control.

Comment: Michael, sounds good. Of course FYI I'm taking source control/project interchangeably here :) so if not in source then also not in the VS project of course.